# Amazon FSx: Change delegated administrators

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-fsx

Is it possible to update the Delegated Administrators group of the FSx service after it iscreated?

We have configured the delegated group to be "Admins du domaine" but I didn't find any way to update this option to another group in our Active Directory.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible at the moment. I got response from AWS support that there is a feature request for that. But at the moment you need to make sure that the group you choose initialy for delegated administrators is the correct one.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).